# Passing data back to form in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have 2 actions in my controller. First action to display form and fetch lists for the form fields from related HABTM models. Second action to perform searching and display results.

First action:

```
public function advancedSearch() {
    $this->set($this->Restaurant->fetchRelatedData());    
}
```

Also I have View for this action which displays the form: **advancedSearch.ctp**

```
echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
        'type' => 'get',
        'url' => '/restaurants/search', 'inputDefaults' => array(
        'label' => false,
        'div' => false
)));

echo $this->Form->input('companyname', array('label' => 'Name:'));
echo $this->Form->input('addr', array('label' => 'Address:'));
echo $this->Form->input('district_id', array('label' => 'District:'));
echo $this->Form->input('Station', array('label' => 'Subway station(s):'));
// etc.

echo $this->Form->end('Go!');
```

As you can see, this form sends data to my second action which performs actual searching.
I need to mention that I use pagination component in my search action and because of this I use the GET method.

My problem is that user may select some "simple" fields and some multiselect fields, send the form and after that he may want to refine search result.
So I need to implement functionality to pass data back to my form and populate fields with values which user has selected before. 
How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: this wheel has already been invented - it's called search plugin: https://github.com/cakedc/search . and it even uses a few better approaches than yours (keyword PRG)

Comment: Thanks, I think this is very useful plugin but is it able to help me with my problem? I did not notice search refining functionality in it. Hope I'm wrong.

Comment: I am sry to have to destroy your view of reality :) but "passing" data back to the view for redefining the search terms is also a key feature of it. you can easily do that using the "presetVars" key in the controller - as documented.

Comment: Can you not just add the "redefining" fields into the form, submit them, and return them via the Controller's `$this->set()`?  The search() plugin might be good, but good luck learning it - the documentation for the CakeDC plugins are NOT easy to follow for someone new to Cake.

Comment: @Dave It looks like I don't understand something with $this->set(). Where I should use it? I have 2 view files – with form and with search results and 2 actions related to this views.

Functionality that I need is: The user sees the form, fills in some of the fields, submits the form and gets a page with results. After that, he can click the link and go back to the form. The form must be filled in with fields (including select/checkboxes) which he chose before.
 
Tell me if you need to see all of my code to make things clear. Thank you.